# How can i perform group by with where conditions using Accumulators in mongodb java?

Tags: java, mongodb

actual documents:

```
Document{{ID=7, NAME=trrrrr, amount=700}}
Document{{ID=6, NAME=kjjdj, amount=100}}
Document{{ID=5, NAME=dgsdg, amount=500}}
Document{{ID=2, NAME=fdfd, amount=200}}
Document{{ID=1, NAME=cggggg, amount=600}}
Document{{ID=3, NAME=kjhfjh, amount=300}}
```

below is the code:

```
 MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("db");
 MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("test");
 BsonField id = Accumulators.first("ID", "$ID");
 BsonField amount = Accumulators.first("amount", "$amount");
 Bson group = Aggregates.group("$NAME",ID,NAME,amount);
```

now how can i get documents group by NAME and ID<=5

Comment: As the dupe suggests, use the `$match` pipeline stage before `$group` as it passes all documents matching the specified filter to the next stage: 
`Arrays.asList( Aggregates.match(Filters.lte("ID", 5)), Aggregates.group("$NAME", ID, NAME, amount) )`

Comment: It worked @chridam